# Trouble getting AJAX to generate the correct values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Trying to generate a list of values based on a selection from the user selection, the AJAX should be generating a second list based on the users selection from the first selection field.

The form is

```
<form id="fitment_search" action="wheels_search_results.php" method="GET">
    <div class="heading">
        <h4>Car search</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">Vehicle Make:
        <select name="car_make"  onchange="get_model(this.value)">
            <option value="width">SELECT</option>
                <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($makeResult)) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['make']; ?>"><?php echo $row['make']; ?></option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">Vehicle Model:
        <select name="car_model" id="fitment_model">
            <option>Any</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">Wheel Diam:
        <select name="diam">
            <option value="diam">SELECT</option>
        <?php mysqli_data_seek($diamQuery, 0); ?>
            <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($diamQuery)) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['diam']; ?>"><?php echo $row['diam']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="fitment_button" value="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Search Now</button>
</form>
```

The AJAX

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_model(str){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else    {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("fitment_model").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","fitment_models.php?make="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

Fitment Model which is called

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/core/init.php");

$make=$_GET["make"];

#$sql2 = "SELECT distinct model FROM fitment WHERE make='".$make."' ORDER BY model ASC";
$sql2 = "SELECT model, yr FROM fitment WHERE make='".$make."' ORDER BY model ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($sql2); ?>
<select name="models"> <?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['model'] ?>:<?php echo $row['yr'] ?>"><?php echo $row['model'] ?> <?php echo $row['yr'] ?></option><?php
} ?>
</select>
```

So basically it should generate a list of models from the DB based on the make selected in the form, currently the make is working, diam is working but the model doesn't display any information.

[image]

Comment: the ajax request is sent ? You can check this in the inspector of your browser.If is sent your php script produces any errors?your query returns results or not?

Comment: I've added a screenshot, it appears to be sending to the .php file.

Comment: ok Your query returns results?You can check with mysqli_num_rows($result).It should be greater than 0.Also you can print $sql2 and copy paste to your mysql client and see.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I can't give you a best answer as you didn't answer. I played around with it and sorted it based on your advice.